# Databricks : Error with while creating External Table on Event Hub Capture

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

[image: select directly from avro files]

[image: External Table on Event Hub Capture]

querying captured avro files works while creating external table is failing with error - Failure to initialize configuration for storage account XXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

Comment: Your URL obfuscation is quite poor tbh .. how exactly is this related to Unity?

Comment: I think he meant databricks-unity-catalog...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I do need to get this working now.  Credential here is based on Azure databricks Access connector - which Managed Identity and has Storage Blob Contributor role on underneath storage account (data lake gen2). I believe Create External Table must be internally trying to use mount point (with service principal based auth) instead of MI.  I don't understand why select statement works while create external table fails here. Is this limitation of Unity Catalog ?

Answer (score 0):

recursive File lookup along with ignore extension resolved the issue.
Here is SQL. The query performance is not good at all, I ended up using structured streaming into delta table as its faster, cheaper and better than this technique.

```sql
DROP TABLE if exists dev.raw_corporate_it.extPolicyServiceLog;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists dev.raw_corporate_it.extPolicyServiceLog
using AVRO
OPTIONS(
  recursiveFileLookup "true", 
  ignoreExtension "true",
  PATH "abfss://XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/evhns-policyservice-prod/evh-policyservice-log/"
)
```